# Excel: Number stored as text duplicate false-positive

Tags: microsoft-excel

#### Situation:

I'm creating a rough and hopefully temporary EPOS system using just excel for overall simplicity, and I'm at the point of adding stock to inventory. This requires scanning modified barcodes into a column with corresponding data in the following columns. The modified barcodes (>1000) have a length of 17 digits (12 UPC + 5 Ext) which are required to correctly identify unique variants of the same item (Comics for example with different covers of the same issue). I already took the initiative to set this column as text as I would require any leading zeros to be accounted for, and generally the barcode will never have any math applied to it. However I also formatted for duplicates in that column to avoid errors of duplicate entries.

#### The Problem:

Despite the cells being treated as text, Excel must clearly still be reading them as numbers for the sake of comparison as both the 16th and 17th digits are not being accounted for and causing false positives.

#### Notes:

- If I append a non-numerical character to the value, it will then correctly identify as unique (even if the same non-numerical character is used). This - unfortunately - cannot be used as a solution as that would require re-printing 1000's of barcodes which is an unreasonable cost and timesink for our current scale.
- Appending an apostrophe to the start of the barcode which would normally cause the value to be treated as text still results in the false-positive. Additionally, the apostrophe becomes impossible to remove without deleting the range of applied cells as excel automatically re-inserts the character when removed.

#### Ideal fix:

- Force excel to treat a range/column as literal text regardless of non-numerical content

#### Disclaimer:

I have read hours worth of questions on Stack Exchange and other sites regarding this type of problem - all of which are solved with "format as text". This is not the solution to this problem, and I have yet to find another question with this specific problem, so I do not believe this to be a duplicate.

Thanks for any help guys!

#### Edits (based on replies/suggested answers):

- Column/cells that required text were formatted to text **before** any data entry.
- Data entered directly via barcode scanner which auto-carriage-returns with no leading/trailing characters (non-printing or otherwise).
- Highlight Duplicates functionality mentioned above was the default Excel: Styles>Conditional Formatting>Highlight Cell Rules>Duplicate Values.
- A Helper Column *can and is* being used to work around the problem (appending "#" infront of barcodes) - however I don't consider this a permanent solution due to the limited computer resources available that this column drains (noticeable impact on performance as inventory grows larger).

Comment: Set text type for the value explicitly by adding a quote as 1st char of your barcode. I.e. enter not `12345678901234567`, but `'12345678901234567`. This quote will be automatically removed whle accessing both cell.formula and cell.value.

Comment: The column needs to be set as text **PRIOR** to entering any data.  Is that being done?

Comment: @Akina - Adding the apostrophe will force formatting to text on a per-cell basis. But as mentioned in the question: this still results in a false-positive as Excel seems to still interpret this as a number when detecting duplicates thereby only looking upto 15SD

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Column A (barcodes) was set to Text prior to entry. I even created a new spreadsheet, just to confirm I didn't do a dumb (wouldn't be the first time honestly) and still the same problem.

Comment: *But as mentioned in the question: this still results in a false-positive as Excel seems to still interpret this as a number when detecting duplicates* I cannot reproduce. I see they are compared as text.

Comment: @Akina [link](https://imgur.com/5fc8fb1) this shows entry into excel for the example of Col A: Format as text prior to entry, and Col B: Apostrophe infront of data.
While both cause the data to be interpreted as text (as evidenced by the green warning triangle about improper data typing) it still results in the conditional formatting default of Highlight Duplicates to only read the 15 most significant digits.

Comment: You have not said that you need to check this in Conditional formatting previously. It really fails in direct compare (COUNTIF), whereas single compare gives correct result.

Comment: @Akina sorry if that wasn't clear enough in the main question. But thanks for the help all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight your duplicates a Conditional Format `use a formula` method.

Other methods seem to have an issue where text is a "long" number.

See [Find duplicates in a column with large number as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960322/find-duplicates-in-a-column-with-large-number-as-text)

Assuming your barcodes are in A1:A10000 (with the limited resources, you don't want to have your range any larger than it might eventually grow to).

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(N($A1=$A$1:$A$10000))>1,LEN($A1)>0)
```

or

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(--($A1=$A$1:$A$10000))>1,LEN($A1)>0)
```

[image]

Comment: This certainly is a more functional work-around for the excel limitation of 15 significant digits.
I will mark this as a solution to the question as it does eliminate the need for any additional helper columns/cells, and works purely in conditional formatting.
However it's a shame that it isn't possible to change how far excel looks into significant digits.
Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @CubeyAlchemist There is a feedback option within Excel whereby you can make suggestions to the team.  This issue has been around for years (see the link in my answer), but the more requests, the more likely something will change.

Answer (score 0):

If the input column is already formatted as text before data entry, that is not the source of difficulty. You say that is so, so moving on...

If all you do is look up a value using the input values, and the values being searched have also been formatted as text before their own entry, Excel will do this. Period.

There is a failure point available here:  Absolutely all the data entry in both columns must occur AFTER the columns are set as text.

Unfortunately, if you ever force Excel to regard them as numbers after they are properly (see above) entered, you've ruined it. So, for example, if you want to be "rigorous" and clean your data for the searching by making sure it all has the same number of characters or what-have-you, and do that by using, say, `TEXT()` to apply an exact format to the values, you are forcing them through the 15 significant digits mill and will see them truncated as you do. That's just one way they can be forced to be regarded as numbers without you really thinking about it. (For example, making sure all have 17 digits by using, say, `TEXT(A1,"00000000000000000")`, so as to avoid frustrations that come from certain ways bar code readers present their output (ways that are chosen by users, mind you, or present because they are not selected away, not failure on the readers' parts).

Moving on, I will cite the fact that you say adding deinitive non-numrical text makes things come out all right. Yes, because Excel is no longer treating them as numbers. That suggests something, a "monkey in the middle" that is taking properly formatted and entered data and treating it as a number before your lookups are performed.

So we come to the likely point of failure here:  (quoting from your questions)

"However I also formatted for duplicates in that column to avoid errors of duplicate entries."

Dude... just what does that mean? Whatever in the world does it include? For example, there simply isn't ANY "formatting for duplicates" functionality in Excel. So this suggests, pretty strongly, you are NOT looking up in the stored data directly, `and/or` not using the bar code reader entered data, DIRECTLY. It suggests that you have helper columns that have a version of one or more of these columns undergoing `IF()` testing to "remove" duplicates by presenting blanks ("") in the helper column.

VERY suggestive that the problem is these formulas treat the entries as numbers at some point rather than always treating them as text, start to finish. And...

Even more of a problem...

Those helper columns cannot be formatted as text or their formulas can't work. So even if you never treat either the entered data or the stored lookup data as numbers in this duplicate hunt, the results of the formulas are beign treated as numbers!

So their outputs are numbers.

Hence the truncation.

I'd give all that a strong look-see.

Comment: Excel has default functionality with conditional formatting to highlight duplicates/uniques. A similar method can be manually achieved by conditional formatting with the following custom formula: "=countif($A$2:$A2,$A2)>1" where Column A is the values to check.

Comment: The inventory table where Barcodes are stored directly into Column A (Scanned in with a barcode reader that auto-returns after entry) is referenced from a sales tab which vlookup's the barcode scanned at sale with the inventory list, taking the first true match (match type 0 i believe). The functionality of it works perfectly regarding the EPOS process - it's purely the formatting of cells that appears to have this monkey-in-the-middle as you put it that is the problem for a more streamlined approach.

Comment: I have also temporarily used a "helper" column which appends a non-numeric character to the barcodes (which can be shorter or longer than 17 characters, but that's the norm), and used the custom formula mentioned before to highlight the row based on the helper column. The problem with this is processing power - as the file is run on a very limited-resource computer. A column of a few thousand entries to be checked by formula then conditional formatting does make a noticeable impact on performance - which is why I would like an alternative solution if possible. Thank you for your help though :)